# Is additional authorization needed with react-google-login?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, google-signin

I recently read an [article on Medium](https://medium.com/@alexanderleon/implement-social-authentication-with-react-restful-api-9b44f4714fa) stating that you need to authenticate the token provided by google. From my understanding, you needed to:

1. Get `react-google-login` working with your react app
2. From the `response` add what you need to your database

Am I missing something of how to properly set this up? It is necessary to also return a JWT token to the frontend? Also I am a frontend dev who is trying to learn more backend stuff and want to know how to properly sign/register a user using react.